# Why does Lightning have branches?

Tags: electricity, lightning

Why does lightning have branches? A straight line from the clouds to the ground should be the path of least resistance, then why does it branch out?

If it is because of different gases present in air then would lightning be a straight line if the air had uniform composition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does lightning generate multiple branches?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185119/)